# Base UIViewController has portrait orientation bounds instead of landscape- why?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, interface-orientation

All of my `ViewController` classes inherit from `MyBaseViewController` which has a custom `viewDidLoad` method:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    int x = self.view.bounds.size.width / 2;
    int y = self.view.bounds.size.height / 2;

    self.spinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x, y, 50, 50)];
    self.spinner.activityIndicatorViewStyle = UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray;

    [self.view addSubview:self.spinner];

    [self.spinner startAnimating];
}
```

Each child class calls `[super viewDidLoad]` in its own `viewDidLoad` method. However, the spinner is always 'centered' as though the device is in portrait mode, rather than landscape, and the application is locked to landscape mode, as you can see here:

[image]

Why is this?

Comment: Why doesn't this `viewDidLoad` call `[super viewDidLoad];`? It should.

Comment: Yes, a duplicate indeed. The answer here is simple, golden, and very 101.

Answer (score 0):

The calling sequence of view controller methods as below :-

1) viewDidLoad
2) viewWillAppear
3) viewDidAppear

The BaseviewController as Parent class in your case. When Child class loaded then it will call your child class orientation method. You need to call your base class viewcontroller method once child class orientation method get called.

Please check your orientation method get called or not.
So Activity indicator will show middle of the screen.

Also try to avoid writing orientation code in viewDidLoad method. Please add your code in viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear method.

Comment: Problem is I am calling a web service during `viewDidLoad` and would like to show an activity indicator.

Comment: YES. Because your view is not appeared and you written code in viewDidLoad. Once your view will appeared then you have to show activity indicator That will show you proper output.